# boost filesystem copy_file "successful" but no files copied

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems, boost-filesystem

im having trouble figuring out why my files wont copy. Here's a brief portion of the code:

(`dir_itr` is directory_iterator & `root` is a path)

```
if (!(is_directory(dir_itr->path())))
{
    cout << "copying: " << dir_itr->path().filename() << endl;
    try
    {
        copy(dir_itr->path(), root);
        remove(dir_itr->path());
    } catch (filesystem_error& ex) {
        //more code
```

The results are as follows in the command window:

```
boost::filesystem::copy_file: The operation completed successfully: 
"C:\Documents and Settings\R\Desktop\New Folder\New Folder (2)\New Bitmap Image 3.bmp", 
"C:\Documents and Settings\R\Desktop\New Folder"
```

However no files are copied over.

I am basically just trying to move said file from folder `c:\x\y\file.file` to `c:\x`

I'm assuming why i cant move it is because i need a full file name and not just a directory or something? If this is the case, how do i convert path root to string so i can add a file name to it? (im gettin a thousand errors if i even try, they're so long i cant scroll all the way back up the window to see where it starts)

Comment: Your output doesn't match your source code. I don't see any of the `"copying"` statements.

Comment: oh i didnt copy all of the output because theres a loopstatement in there and a lot more cout's.

the "boost::filesystem::copy_file: The operation completed successfully:" plus the next two lines, is what is automatically printed by the boost filesystem when you use the copy_file function,

the output really isnt an issue, its just that im not seeing any results

Comment: I rather doubt that `boost::filesystem` functions actually output strings as part of their operation. Are you sure that isn't coming from something else?

Comment: I dont know what else it could be coming from, because it surely isnt coming from my code. The cmd window perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [boost::filesystem::system_complete](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#system_complete) can help:

(Sorry, I'm on my Mac and not windows but it shows a way to get the absolute path from a relative path).  Good luck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    boost::filesystem::path cwd(".");
    boost::filesystem::path resolved = boost::filesystem::system_complete(cwd);

    std::cout << cwd << std::endl;
    std::cout << resolved << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
"."
"/private/var/folders/qw/x23nm9f11fxc45rgddb04n_w0000gn/T/CodeRunner/."
```

Answer (score 0):

Got back to working on this and I added/changed the following:

```
try
{
    string temp = root.string() + "\\" + dir_itr->path().filename().string();
    path p(temp);
    copy(dir_itr->path(), p);
    remove(dir_itr->path());
//more code
```

And it seemed to work. I guess my assumption of needing to include the file name when copying was correct.